# Run the ASIHTTPRequest in background when View reloads

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nsurl

I am developing a application which uses ASIHTTPRequest to download the content from server. When downloading if I move from Portrait to Landscape mode the downloads process is going to stop. I need the download process still to be continued.

I have searched for the solution in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913859/asihttprequest-and-background) but no useful.

How can I solve this problem...

This is the piece of code i am using to download.

```
   NSURL *downloadURL = [publisher contentURLForIssueWithName:issueTitle];

    if (!networkQueue) {
        networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
    }

    if(!downloadURL) return;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(read) withObject:nil];

    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
    [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground=YES;
    request.allowResumeForFileDownloads=YES;
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Any help to be appreciated..

Comment: Do you have code where you do something according to device rotation change? Maybe there is a reason.

Comment: No. Its just for viewing Portrait to landscape and vice versa.

Comment: Here you have a maybe useful for you documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24
 search there: "Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks"